# Apache HttpAsyncClient response not received

Tags: java, servlets, apache-httpclient-4.x

In my servlet, I am executing the following code:

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setSocketTimeout(3000).setConnectTimeout(3000).build();
CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();

        try 
        {
            client.start();

            for (String request : preparedURLs) 
            {
                client.execute(new HttpGet(request), new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>()  
                {
                    public void failed(Exception ex) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("\n\nRequest Failed Due to : " + ex.getMessage());
                    }

                    public void completed(HttpResponse response) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("\n\nRequest COMPLETED");
                    }

                    public void cancelled() 
                    {
                        System.out.println("\n\nRequest CANCELLED");
                    }
                });

             System.out.println("\n\n" + request);
            }
        } 
        finally 
        {
            System.out.println("\n*** Finally called ***\n\n");
            client.close();
        }
```

But I don't get any response at all. Following is printed in my `catalina.out`:

```
http://localhost:8080/servlet/?ps=true


http://localhost:8080/servlet/?ps=true


http://localhost:8080/servlet/?ps=false

*** Finally called ***
```

I have wrote this code, taking [this](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/httpasyncclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/client/AsyncClientHttpExchangeFutureCallback.java) as example from apache's official site.

I have only omitted the latch part. Is this some thing to do with latch?

If possible please explain the reason of failure too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct behaviour. You are creating a socket with a conditional Future,  and then you proceed to close it without waiting for it.
The example code you linked use a "latch" variable to do so.
You may move the close code inside future callback, but probably this will confuse your waring. 
Or you can use the same system of the example,  with a shared synchronised counter (maybe just a final AtomicBoolean triggered by an aswer) and wait for it before continuing with your program flow,  but that destroy the idea of using async call

Comment: "Confuse warning" how?

Comment: PROBABLY it will trow a "possible resource leaking" warning because the system can't see a close in the scope of try/catch block.

but maybe is smart enougth to see it

Answer (score 2):

This latch that you have removed is actually the synchronization part of the example.

The idea of async client is to make some requests and wait for the responses on other thread. By removing the synchronization the execution directly passes to the finally block instead of waiting the responses and closes the HttpAsyncClient.

In order to get it back working add the latch code from the example.

Comment: But that would cause my servlet to wait for all responses and will return only after all request are complete. That's what I want to avoid...
I want my servlet to return immediately, causing all requests to be processed in background.

Comment: Then you have to implement another way of closing the client. 

Possible solutions will be to do this in the in the callback.